# No formatting in exported .xls file using PHP in Linux

Tags: php, codeigniter, export-to-excel

I want to export HTML Generated table in to MS-Excel file using PHP. though i have done it by simple way but facing some issues with style-sheet formatting in exported file.
While i open that exported files in windows system it looks good with proper formatting and data but in linux system for same file there are no formatting.

Can anybody help me solve this issue?

`PHP-Framework  : Codeigniter`
`Windows system : Windows-7`
`Linux System   : Fedora release 15 (Lovelock)`

Code that I have used to export file in Excel.

```
  $HTML_OUTPUT = $this->session->userdata('Report_Data');
  $file="demo.xls";
  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
  echo $HTML_OUTPUT;
```

Comment: How are you opening this file in Linux to check?

Comment: @MarkBaker I am using LibreOffice

Comment: I believe LibreOffice requires the `<html>` tag to be the very first element in your file, otherwise it will parse it as plain text rather than using the html importer, so it will have problems with files where `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` appears as the first line before the `<html>`... that could be the problem

Comment: @MarkBaker is possible to export html generated table into excel file using PHPExcel class ?

Comment: PHPExcel has a very basic HTML Reader, but doesn't support reading styles from html markup